# ADODB RecordSet RecordCount doesn't return useful information

Tags: sql, vb6, adodb

I have a pretty basic execution of a stored procedure in my code:

```
Dim objCmd As ADODB.Command
Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rsTemplate As ADODB.Recordset

Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection
objConn.Open strConnection
Set objCmd = New ADODB.Command
objCmd.ActiveConnection = objConn
objCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
objCmd.CommandText = "GetTemplate"
objCmd.Parameters.Append objCmd.CreateParameter("@Param1", adInteger, adParamInput, , lngParam1)
objCmd.Parameters.Append objCmd.CreateParameter("@Param2", adInteger, adParamInput, , lngParam1)
objCmd.CommandTimeout = 600
Set rsTemplate = objCmd.Execute()
LogInfo "Found " & rsTemplate.RecordCount & " templates"
```

The SP is supposed to find a single row.  The problem is that sometimes it fines none, which is actually okay, except that the `RecordCount` property is -1 in both cases. I would have expected 0 for zero records and 1 for one record. I have another section of code that can return a single or multiple rows, and with my testing parameters, it is returning seven rows, and `RecordCount` is correctly showing 7.  Does anyone know why I'm getting inconsistent results?  I need to be able to skip a subsequent piece of code if I get zero results here, and there's no other good way to check, other than trying to access a bad RecordSet object and having a special handler to `resume next` if it's a particular error code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `strConnection` is such that you are specifiying a forward-only cursor, then the record count will always be `-1` as the result-size cannot be identified with that kind of connection.

From here http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms676701(v=vs.85).aspx

> The cursor type of the Recordset object affects whether the number of
>   records can be determined. The RecordCount property will return -1 for
>   a forward-only cursor; the actual count for a static or keyset cursor;
>   and either -1 or the actual count for a dynamic cursor, depending on
>   the data source.

Comment: Well I'll be. I use the same connection string for both, but I had added the line `objConn.CursorLocation = adUseClient` in the second case while attempting to solve another problem.  Will accept in a few minutes. Thanks!

Comment: Setting the CursorLocation of the ADODB.Connection object to adUseClient was the only thing that made RecordCount work properly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in your stored procedure `GetTemplate`, you have enabled the row count.

Example:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[GetTemplate] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF -- Enable row count here
    ...

END
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't include the line `SET NOCOUNT OFF`? Does it create problems? Just wondering why it's not a default setting.

Comment: It's faster and more efficient to have `no count` enabled (especially if you're running the query thousands of times, and don't really care about the number of rows affected.) But if you do care about the result, then you need to set `no count` to off.

Comment: Hm, I am able to get the record count without including that line in the stored procedure.

Comment: The option is disabled by default. My answer applies only if you had wrongly set the property to `SET NOCOUNT ON`.

Comment: I am able to get the record count with the line `SET NOCOUNT ON` in the stored procedure as well, which is how it is in the second SP I mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

dim FindRecordCount as integer

If rsTemplate.EOF Then
         FindRecordCount = 0
          Else
      rsTemplate.MoveLast
          FindRecordCount = rstRecords.AbsolutePosition
       End If

Maybe you can try something like this

Comment: Yeah, that would probably work, but I'm glad to get the `RecordCount` itself working properly.

Comment: I think it's working as intended. Again "-1 when ADO cannot determine the number of records or if the provider or cursor type does not support RecordCount". Just create a function that replace recordCount.

Comment: Well my code worked adding the line I mentioned in my comment on the other answer.